# OpenMP and private reusable memory

Tags: c, memory-management, openmp

I have run into issues where too many memory allocations inside parallel sections of my code are causing exceptions. In many cases I have completely solved this by pulling memory allocations out of a loop so that the memory becomes reusable and only allocated again if it needs to grow. This can be simple if the memory is used only within a relatively short and simple parallel loop. For example, imagine the following pseudocode is my original loop:

```
omp parallel for
for 1000 times {
  mem = alloc
  do stuff in mem and get result
  free mem
}
```

Then to make `mem` reusable I can write instead:

```
omp parallel {
  mem = alloc
  omp for
  for 1000 times {
    if mem too small then grow mem
    do stuff in mem and get result
  }
  free mem
}
```

This of course assumes that I have less than 1000 threads, or it makes no difference.

Readability begins to suffer with more complicated loops, particularly because one cannot break out of a parallel section. For example, if I want to abort if memory allocation failed, subsequent chunks of code have to be inside an

```
if(not failed) { 
  do some stuff
}
```

Instead of the nicer

```
if(failed) return
do some stuff
```

It gets significantly worse if a function has lots of parallel regions with serial regions in between and you want to reuse memory throughout those parallel regions. At that point you are essentially making the entire function parallel and then explicitly marking the serial sections.

It occurred to me that OpenMP's `threadprivate` clause can save a lot of headache. It allows you to make private copies of global variables. Then it becomes pretty easy to make a reusable chunk of memory for your entire program, not to mention a single function. If you believe global variables are good style then it seems like a no-brainer.

Am I misunderstanding something, or is making everything I want to reuse global going to result in a lot less work than keeping variables inside functions? And if so, is there no "function level" equivalent of `threadprivate`?

(I should mention I am in Visual Studio 2012 which is stuck with OpenMP 2.0 and apparently can't do things like change the OpenMP private thread stack size. I need to stay in Windows so I may switch to Intel's compiler if a newer version of OpenMP could help me significantly.)

Answer (score 0):

`threadprivate` is the OpenMP version of the `__thread` variable attribute, with the right compiler options they are even compatible. It resides in thread local storage. You can put a pointer into thread-local storage, but you will have to make sure to free that memory when the thread exits which is difficult with OpenMP.

If you have to allocate a lot of memory (more then your stack size) then I am afraid what you are doing is as best as it gets. Otherwise consider putting your memory on the stack which is guaranteed to be freed when the thread exits.

Also it is good practice to keep the code that resides in the parallel regions as small as possible and move everything into separate functions (which is what OpenMP does for you under the hood anyways).

What you probably need it a good multi-threaded memory allocator. I have read good stuff about [Hoard](http://www.hoard.org/), but never tried it.

Comment: Indeed, OpenMP "forces" you to put things in functions or you go crazy, particularly since `default (none)` crashes VS2012 on build.